# Python Guess game with tries option

Tags: python, python-3.x, helper

I’m working on a python guessing game to learn how python works.

I want to add an option to count the number of guesses, but if the player gives the same answer multiple times, I want to count that as 1 try.

I don’t know how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated :)

Here's my current script

```py
# The Guess Game   

# secret number between 1 and 10 
import random
randomNumber = random.randrange(1,10)
#print randomNumber #check if it's working
tries = 0

# rules
print('Hello and welcome to the guess game !')
print('The number is between 1 and 10')

guessed = False
tries += 1

while guessed==False:

    userInput = int(input("Please enter your guess: "))

    if userInput==randomNumber:
        guessed = True
        tries = str(tries)
        print("Congratulations ! You win after " + tries + " tries ! ")

    elif userInput>10:
        print("The guess range is between 1 and 10, please try again")
        tries = tries + 1

    elif userInput<1:
        print("The guess range is between 1 and 10, please try again")
        tries = tries + 1

    elif userInput>randomNumber:
        print("Your guess is too large")
        tries = tries + 1

    elif userInput < randomNumber:
        print("Your guess is too small")
        tries = tries + 1

print("End of the game, please play again")
```

Comment: Welcome Julien! Can you say specifically what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Jon if one person guesses the same X times in a row, he only wants to count that one time

Comment: You can use a `set()` for previously guessed numbers and check if number is in the previously guessed set

Comment: Be careful, you are using 10 and 100 as they are the same value. The code you described doesn't seem to work as you explain. And what is your question?

Comment: also, you may want to add a break in the body of the condition where the user guesses correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first. You're claiming the number is between 1 and 100 and only picking a number between 1 and 10.

Change `randomNumber = random.randrange(1,10)` to `randomNumber = random.randrange(1, 100)`

You're also checking if the number is greater than 10 instead of 100 when verifying the user input. Change `elif userInput>10` to `elif userInput > 100`.

Now, as others have mentioned, in order to keep track of the guesses, you can use a `set`. A set is a data structure (basically, a way to store information) that only allows a single copy of each distinct item you add to it.

Using a set you can easily check if  number has already been guessed like so:

```py
guess = int(input())
if guess not in guesses:
    guesses.add(guess)
```

Lastly, instead of adding 1 to tries in every if, you can add 1 right after you read your guess. You can also merge your  `elif userInput > 100` and `elif userInput < 1` together since they print the same thing.

Full code:

```py
# The Guess Game   

# secret number between 1 and 100 
import random
randomNumber = random.randrange(1, 100)  # changed from 10 to 100
#print randomNumber #check if it's working

# rules
print('Hello and welcome to the guess game !')
print('The number is between 1 and 100')

guesses = set()  # your set of guesses
guessed = False
tries = 0        # no need add 1 to the tries here

while guessed == False:

    userInput = int(input("Please enter your guess: "))

    if userInput not in guesses:   # if it's not in our set
        tries += 1                 # increase the tries
        guesses.add(userInput)     # add it to our set

    if userInput == randomNumber:
        guessed = True
        tries = str(tries)
        print("Congratulations ! You win after " + tries + " tries ! ")

    elif userInput > 100 or userInput < 1:
        print("The guess range is between 1 and 100, please try again")

    elif userInput > randomNumber:
        print("Your guess is too large")

    elif userInput < randomNumber:
        print("Your guess is too small")

print("End of the game, please play again")
```

Extra: **Always** make sure your user gives you the input you're expecting. Look into what happens when you run this program and the user inputs "asdfg". Hint: look into python exceptions.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for the edit suggestion and the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find it useful, you can accept it (by clicking the 'tick' buton underneath the vote counter). If not, let me know how I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you trying to accomplish with the code. Nevertheless, if you want that the user repeating the same number does not count as another trial you should keep a record of the already imputed tries (In an array for instance) and check if the current try is among the already used ones beforehand.

Furthermore, I guess you should not increase the number of tries if the user gives a number outside the allowed range. Also you should check if the input is larger than 100 not 10 and you could do it in the same elif statement.Like:

```
elif userInput<1 or userInput>100:
```

As you requested I give you a full example:

```
# The Guess Game   

# secret number between 1 and 100 
import random
randomNumber = random.randrange(1,10)
#print randomNumber #check if it's working
tries = 0

# rules
print('Hello and welcome to the guess game !')
print('The number is between 1 and 10')

guessed = False
tries += 1
past_tries = set()

while guessed==False:

    userInput = int(input("Please enter your guess: "))

    if userInput in past_tries:
        print("This guess is repeated!")

    elif userInput==randomNumber:
        guessed = True
        tries = str(tries)
        print("Congratulations ! You win after " + tries + " tries ! ")

    elif userInput>10 or userInput<1:
        print("The guess range is between 1 and 100, please try again")

    elif userInput>randomNumber:
        print("Your guess is too large")
        tries = tries + 1

    elif userInput < randomNumber:
        print("Your guess is too small")
        tries = tries + 1

    past_tries.add(userInput)

print("End of the game, please play again")
```

Comment: Hi again, Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `set` to store the user's guesses, a set data structure doesn't allow duplicates. you can flush the set after the user guesses correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `set` to keep track of the inputs that the user has already given. If the userinput is already present in the set, don't increment the `tries` counter.

```
# The Guess Game

# secret number between 1 and 100
import random
randomNumber = random.randrange(1,10)
#print randomNumber #check if it's working
tries = 0

# rules
print('Hello and welcome to the guess game !')
print('The number is between 1 and 100')

guessed = False
tries += 1
user_inputs = set()  # to keep track of inputs

while not guessed:

    userInput = int(input("Please enter your guess: "))
    user_inputs.add(userInput)

    if userInput==randomNumber:
        guessed = True
        tries = str(tries)
        print("Congratulations ! You win after " + tries + " tries ! ")

    elif userInput in user_inputs:  # if already seen this guess, don't increment the counter
        print("You had already guessed this number earlier")
        continue

    elif userInput>10:
        print("The guess range is between 1 and 100, please try again")
        tries = tries + 1

    elif userInput<1:
        print("The guess range is between 1 and 100, please try again")
        tries = tries + 1

    elif userInput>randomNumber:
        print("Your guess is too large")
        tries = tries + 1

    elif userInput < randomNumber:
        print("Your guess is too small")
        tries = tries + 1

print("End of the game, please play again")
```

Comment: The code will never reach the condition you wrote. Maybe you should write it after the `if`.